# Using sprintf to change a double to a string in MPLAB IDE v6.20

Tags: c, printf, mplab, harmony

I have been using the console to print (through UART) it has always worked fine but for some reason every time I use `sprintf` it seems to lock up the system and not allow me to print the string value or any other string in a buffer.

This is the part of my code that contributes to it.I am using MPLAB which has the harmony framework and uses FreeRTOS.

```c
#include "app.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "system/console/sys_console.h"
#include "peripheral\sercom\usart\plib_sercom_usart_common.h"
#include "system/console/src/sys_console_uart.h"
#include "peripheral\port\plib_port.h"
#include "interrupts.h"
#include "peripheral\sercom\i2c_master\plib_sercom1_i2c_master.h"
#include "MC3416_Accel.h"

SYS_CONSOLE_HANDLE New_Console;
uint8_t limit = 0;
static char tilt_string[20];

void Acc_Task (void){
 if (limit < 1)
    {
     limit++;
     
     mc3416_accel_init();
     mc3416_accel_read_tilt();

     double tilt = mc3416_accel_get_tilt();
       
     while (SYS_CONSOLE_Status(New_Console) != SYS_STATUS_READY)
     {}
       
    int result = sprintf(tilt_string,"%.2f",tilt);
       
       
    SYS_CONSOLE_Write(New_Console, tilt_string, strlen(tilt_string));
  }
}


//The accelerometer initialize function calls on a function that sets the accel to wake_mode (i2c communication) and uses this function to send a message when finished.

/***************************************************************************
Function to send a message to the console
****************************************************************************/
void mc3416_send_message(const char *message)
{
    
    SYS_CONSOLE_Write(New_Console, message ,strlen(message));
    
    while(SYS_CONSOLE_Status(New_Console) != SYS_STATUS_READY)
    {
        
    }

}
```

I can see that my value does come and gets changed into a string (through debugging) but for some reason it doesn't allow anything to happen after.

I have tried `snprintf` and also not printing the string from `sprintf` but something else after calling `sprintf` it still does not work. Please help

I wrote an elementary way to convert the double to a string (doubleToString(tilt,tilt_string,3);) and it does work and allows everything else to work so I thought it was safe to assume the while loop worked ok. I placed it in the same place I had sprintf.

```c
void intToString(int num, char *str) {
     int i = 0;
     if (num == 0) {
         str[i++] = '0';
     } else {
     
         if (num < 0) {
             str[i++] = '-';
             num = -num;
         }
    
         int divisor = 1;
         while (num / divisor > 0) {
             divisor *= 10;
         }
         divisor /= 10;
         while (divisor > 0) {
             int digit = num / divisor;
             str[i++] = '0' + digit;
             num %= divisor;
              divisor /= 10;
         }
     }

     str[i] = '\0';
 }

void doubleToString(double num, char *str, int precision) {

 int intPart = (int)num;
 intToString(intPart, str);

 
 while (*str != '\0') {
     str++;
 }

 if (precision > 0) {
     *str++ = '.';
 }

 double fracPart = num - intPart;
 for (int i = 0; i < precision; ++i) {
     fracPart *= 10;
     int digit = (int)fracPart;
     *str++ = '0' + digit;
     fracPart -= digit;
 }

 *str = '\0';
}
```

Comment: Are you able to write another string in place of `tilt_string`?

Comment: *") but for some reason it doesn't allow anything to happen after."* can you elaborate?

Comment: In the code presented, it seems far more likely that the `while` loop does not terminate than that the `sprintf()` does not terminate or prevents subsequent work from proceeding.  How are you differentiating between those two possibilities?

Comment: If you just `printf("%.2f", tilt);` what do you see?

Comment: However, what is the range of values you might see in `tilt`?  You might well cause yourself trouble if it is ever so large that the `sprintf` overruns the bounds of `tilt_string`.  Which it certainly could with the conversion specifier you are using, for many larger values within the range of `double`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger exactly why I just want to see it printed.

Comment: @ECE Student "I have tried snprintf " --> post that code, a [mcve].  "I can see that my value does come" --> post that value.

Comment: @ECE Student, Does code first call `SYS_CONSOLE_Initialize()`?

Comment: @Barmar I have a buffer (char Task_Name[32] = "Task 1 is running!\r\n";) that I tried sending to the console to write both with and without trying to write tilt_string. It does not work as long as sprintf or snprintf is there.

Comment: @gulpr not only does it not print but on the board I am using there is a way to toggle power on a certain component using DETECTPWREN_Toggle(); so i have been using to see that if it toggles then obviously code after the sprintf runs however with sprintf it does not toggle and without it does. So I concluded that not only does it not write to the console it locks the system overall.

Comment: @Chris It returns an error, this is some of it.                                                                

c:/program files (x86)/atmel/studio/7.0/toolchain/arm/arm-gnu-toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/6.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v6-m\libg.a(lib_a-isattyr.o): In function `_isatty_r':
isattyr.c:(.text._isatty_r+0xc): undefined reference to `_isatty'
*IT SAYS THE SAME THING ABOUT `_close_r' `_fstat_r' AND `_lseek_r*
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: @JohnBollinger I appologize for not being more clear i added more to my post to clarify. When debugging I can see that "tilt=89.1315323187966" after sprintf "tilt_string="89.13\0¥¥¥¥¥¥\0\0\0\0¥¥¥¥"" . It seems that after performing it something about sprintf causes the system to not be able to do anything else.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I have functions called before sprintf that write to the console and it works every time so i know the console is up and running. MPLAB has everything sectioned off so there is a file that initializes everything once the program is run.

Comment: Given the newly proffered information about the value of `tilt`, I see nothing wrong with the `sprintf` call for that value, and the debugging details seem to show that `sprintf` is in fact performing the correct conversion.  If that call itself is indeed having an unwanted side effect then I'm prepared to attribute that to a serious flaw in your standard library implementation, as combined with your hardware.

Comment: @ECEStudent `doubleToString()` is broken when the value is 1) outside the `int` range, 2) equal to `INT_MIN` 3) various negative values like -1.23, -0.123.  It also does not form a rounded value, yet that issue is for later improvement.  `doubleToString()` and `sprintf()` also do not provide any protection about over writing the destination buffer.   Without a [mcve], we are left guessing, please post one.  Do not assume that the last function call is causing the troubles.  Undefined behavior in a prior call can take a while to manifest itself.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I apologize I am new to this site. Is the added information enough? If not, what exactly is needed?

Comment: @ECEStudent  Post is better.  Please add input used.  How is `Acc_Task()` called?

Comment: @ECEStudent Hmmm, with some compilers, unless code sees `double`, `float` math going on, the math library is not included in the compiler, even if `*printf()` needs it.  For debug, do some math like `int result = sprintf(tilt_string,"%.2f",tilt/3.0);` and/or make certain the math library is part of the compilation.